# jQuery live("click" ... fails on reload of new data to jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am building a webpart with some jQuery frontend functions doing some basic form functions and cannot find where the code is breaking.  Basically when a user clicks a link for a reserved booking a jQuery Dialog pops up and populates rows of checkboxes with an equipment name e.g. bunsen burner, each row also has 2 dropdownlists which allow the client to select how many items and if it is for an individual or a group, the checkbox changes the selected row from disabled to enabled.

What is happening is the disable/enable row does not always work after the first time.  When the dialog is closed the code is removed, so every new dialog opens the form purely with out any residual code from the last, so always a fresh form.  The checkbox change detection uses .live("change" which I have implemented many time before without fail, but for some reason my code fails on the second and subsequent tries.  So it must be breaking after the first form is closed or as the new one is populated and displayed.

I am using jquery-1.7.1, the dialog library is jquery-ui-1.8.16 custom build for webparts built by myself.  All jquery code is run from the $(document).ready state.

3 functions

- `$(".bookingFunctions")` is the link click.
- `$("input:checkbox").live("change")` is the row enable/disable
- `$(".cancel").live("click")` is what I am doing to close the form and remove the code from the DOM

A sample of the populated form objects

**My code is below:**

```
    var $subInfo = null;
    var id = null;

// Open and Load the equipment list dialog
$(".bookingFunctions").live("click", function () {

    id = $(this).find(".itemId").text().trim();
    var name = $(this).find(".itemClassName").text();
    var inquiry = $(this).find("#itemInquiryName_" + id).text();

    $subInfo = $("<div id='equipmentList_" + id + "' class='equipmentList'></div>").dialog({ title: name + " Equipment List for " + inquiry, autoOpen: false, modal: true });
    $subInfo.html("<img src='/_layouts/Images/BGS.Booking.SharePoint/ajax-loader.gif' alt=''/>");

    $.post("/_layouts/BGS.Booking.SharePoint/requestHandler.ashx",
        {
            func: "getEquipList",
            bid: id
        }, function (data) {
            $subInfo.html(data);
        });

    $subInfo.dialog("option", "width", 660);
    $subInfo.dialog("option", "height", 520);
    $subInfo.dialog('open');

    // do live bind for change events on form
    SetLiveChangeForCheckboxes();

    //return false;

});
// Manage the dropdownlists associated with each checkbox (disable/enable)
$("input:checkbox").live("change", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").substr(4);

    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        $("#numOf_" + id).removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#listType_" + id).removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else {
        $("#numOf_" + id).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#listType_" + id).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
$(".cancel").live("click", function () {
    $subInfo.dialog('close');
    $(".equipmentList").remove();
});
```

-- Dialog Sample

```
<ul xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="equipmentList">
    <li class="equipItem" id="item_10">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkboxList" id="chk_10"/> 100 mL beaker
        <select class="listType" id="listType_10">
            <option value="x">Choose</option>
            <option value="1">Class</option>
            <option selected="" value="2">Group</option>
            <option value="3">Individual</option>

        </select>
        <img alt="" src="/_layouts/Images/BGS.Booking.SharePoint/per.png?p=0" class="fr"/>                                                   
        <select class="numOf" id="numOf_10">
            <option value="1">0</option>
            <option value="2">1</option>
            <option selected="" value="3">2</option>
            <option value="4">3</option>
            <option value="5">4</option>
            <option value="6">5</option>
            <option value="7">6</option>

            <option value="8">7</option>
            <option value="9">8</option>
            <option value="10">9</option>
            <option value="11">10</option>
            <option value="12">11</option>
            <option value="13">12</option>
            <option value="14">13</option>
            <option value="15">14</option>
            <option value="16">15</option>

            <option value="17">18</option>
            <option value="18">19</option>
            <option value="19">20</option>
            <option value="20">21</option>

        </select>
    </li>
    <li class="equipItem" id="item_35">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxList" id="chk_35"/> 100 mL measuring cylinder
        <select disabled="disabled" class="listType" id="listType_35">
            <option value="x">Choose</option>

            <option value="1">Class</option>
            <option value="2">Group</option>
            <option value="3">Individual</option>

        </select>
        <img alt="" src="/_layouts/Images/BGS.Booking.SharePoint/per.png?p=0" class="fr"/>
        <select disabled="disabled" class="numOf" id="numOf_35">
            <option value="1">0</option>
            <option value="2">1</option>

            <option value="3">2</option>
            <option value="4">3</option>
            <option value="5">4</option>
            <option value="6">5</option>
            <option value="7">6</option>
            <option value="8">7</option>
            <option value="9">8</option>
            <option value="10">9</option>
            <option value="11">10</option>

            <option value="12">11</option>
            <option value="13">12</option>
            <option value="14">13</option>
            <option value="15">14</option>
            <option value="16">15</option>
            <option value="17">18</option>
            <option value="18">19</option>
            <option value="19">20</option>
            <option value="20">21</option>

        </select>
    </li>
    <img alt="Cancel" src="/_layouts/Images/BGS.Booking.SharePoint/cancel.png" class="cancel fr"/>
    <img alt="Save" src="/_layouts/Images/BGS.Booking.SharePoint/save.png" class="save fr"/>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you link us to your page in question? I don't feel like looking through all of that.

Comment: I honestly didn't read it, but two guesses. First, 'live' is deprecated, use 'on'. Second, I'm guessing you're initializing the dialog multiple times. Destroy it before you re-initialize it

Comment: A link to the page or at least a fiddle would be helpful. Like Walkerneo, I can't bring myself to trace through all the logic purely with mental visualization.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are doing wrong here. Try changing your code like this without using live.

```
//.....................

 $.post("/_layouts/BGS.Booking.SharePoint/requestHandler.ashx",
        {
            func: "getEquipList",
            bid: id
        }, function (data) {
            $subInfo.html(data);

         $subInfo.dialog("option", "width", 660);
         $subInfo.dialog("option", "height", 520);
         $subInfo.dialog('open');

           BindChange();

        });
//.........................


function     BindChange(){
$("input:checkbox").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").substr(4);

    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        $("#numOf_" + id).removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#listType_" + id).removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else {
        $("#numOf_" + id).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#listType_" + id).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

I need to use .live as the dialog is populated dynamically after the DOM is ready!

It looks like the IF statement in the change function isn't working as it should, I am doing some more debugging now so will post what I find.

Comment: Okay so I have modified the .live("change" function and used a switch instead of the IF statement.  It detects whether it is checked or undefined but the .removeAttr("disabled"); lines don't seem to work at all after the first dialog instance is closed.

Kyle, I will stick with live as I will return to an earlier library pre 1.7, and it is being destroyed after each instance is closed!

Comment: SO it turns out the problem is the .removeAttr("disabled") function, for some reason it does not fire after the first form is closed and removed.  I still do not have a fix for this yet!

Comment: Yes I understand you want to use `live` to bind event for new elements. But you can avoid it using my method above. first time its working means there is some issue with event handling. So have a try it in my way.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that something is populated after the DOM is ready is not a criterion for using .live, which is all about event handlers, not content. There appears to be no good reason for using it.

There also appears to be no good reason for creating a new dialog each time one is needed.

It is far more usual to establish a single dialog and reuse it - simply leave the structure and event handlers in place, and change the content. I cannot think of a circumstance where this should not work.

Answer (score 0):

> SO it turns out the problem is the .removeAttr("disabled") function,
>   for some reason it does not fire after the first form is closed and
>   removed. I still do not have a fix for this yet!

Try:

```
$('selector').attr("disabled", false);
```

rather than `removeAttr()`.